# Compare dates and print sum

Tags: python, file

My program must compare dates and print sum of that day/date.
dates will be always on ascending order.

file:

```
09/12/2015|9380.0
09/12/2015|7667.0
10/12/2015|3190.0
14/12/2015|3190.0
14/12/2015|5940.0
```

result:

```
09/12/2015 -> 17047.0
10/12/2015 -> 3190.0
14/12/2015 -> 9130.0
```

This is my program now

```
start = "09/12/2015"
end = "14/12/2015"

startstart = datetime.strptime(start, "%d/%m/%Y")
endend   = datetime.strptime(end,"%d/%m/%Y")

with open("fileName.txt", "r") as report:
    allData = csv.reader(report, delimiter = "|")

    for line in allData:
        dataLine = datetime.strptime(line[0], "%d/%m/%Y")
        if dataLine >= startstart and dataLine <= endend :
            print("{0} -> {1}|".format(line[0], line[1]))
```

my result now with this program:

```
09/12/2015 -> 9380.0
09/12/2015 -> 7667.0
10/12/2015 -> 3190.0
14/12/2015 -> 3190.0
14/12/2015 -> 5940.0
```

Problem is i print every date and price, i need to make one date and sum of all prices for that date.

Comment: Is your file guaranteed to be date ascending ordered?

Comment: Yes i use date function for input

Comment: Simple...keep track of the current_date (summing as you go) and only print when the date changes.

Comment: yes i have problem with that i don't know how to compare date with date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)  to sum the numbers, and use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to keep order like below:

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

start = "09/12/2015"
end = "14/12/2015"

start = datetime.strptime(start, "%d/%m/%Y")
end = datetime.strptime(end, "%d/%m/%Y")

d = defaultdict(float)

with open('file') as f:
    l = [i.split('|') for i in f.read().splitlines()]

for key, value in l:
    d[key] += float(value)

l = sorted(((key, value) for (key, value) in d.items()
            if datetime.strptime(key, "%d/%m/%Y") >= start and
            datetime.strptime(key, "%d/%m/%Y") <= end),
           key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], "%d/%m/%Y"))

for key, value in l:
    print('{} -> {}'.format(key, value))
```

---

However, since you want keep order, I'd also suggest that use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Here's another example, maybe more simple than the above one:

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict
start = "09/12/2015"
end = "14/12/2015"

start = datetime.strptime(start, "%d/%m/%Y")
end = datetime.strptime(end, "%d/%m/%Y")

with open('file') as f:
    l = [i.split('|') for i in f.read().splitlines()]

d = OrderedDict()

for key, value in l:
    date = datetime.strptime(key, "%d/%m/%Y")
    if date >= start and date <= end:
        try:
            d[key] += float(value)
        except KeyError:
            d[key] = float(value)

for key, value in d.items():
    print('{} -> {}'.format(key, value))
```

---

Demo:

```
09/12/2015 -> 17047.0
10/12/2015 -> 3190.0
14/12/2015 -> 9130.0
```

Comment: This will print dates and prices from whole file ?

Comment: @Blurred: Ah...actually it prints the result which you want if you just choose print them. However I've said how to write them into a file in my answer.

Comment: Still can't figure out how i can print date range i want.

Comment: @Blurred: Oh, so you also need keep the date order right?

Comment: When i print doesn't matter how dates and price will be printed, also dates in file will be always on ascending order.

Comment: @Blurred: Ah, sorry. Seems I misunderstood your question. Check the answer now.

Comment: Thanks , i will test both and definitly will start learning dics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99746/discussion-between-redicon-and-kevin-guan).

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
from datetime import strptime
from itertools import groupby

# this could also be written as
#   get_day = lambda row: row[0]
# or as
#   from operator import itemgetter    # thanks to @ShadowRanger!
#   get_day = itemgetter(0)
def get_day(row):
    return row[0]

def get_date(s):
    return strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y")

start = get_date("09/12/2015")
end   = get_date("14/12/2015")

with open("filename.csv", newline='') as inf:
    rows = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='|')
    for day, day_rows in groupby(rows, get_day):
        if start <= get_date(day) <= end:
            day_total = sum(float(v) for d,v in day_rows)
            print("{} -> {}".format(day, day_total))
```

which (on the given input) produces

```
09/12/2015 -> 17047.0
10/12/2015 -> 3190.0
14/12/2015 -> 9130.0
```

as desired.

**Edit:** a lambda is a way to make a nameless function that returns a single value; `fn = lambda x: x[0]` is exactly the same as

```
def fn(x):
    return x[0]
```

I have rewritten it as a separate function instead of a lambda ;-) Hope that helps.

**Edit2:** in this example `groupby` takes

```
[
    ('09/12/2015', '9380.0'),
    ('09/12/2015', '7667.0'),
    ('10/12/2015', '3190.0'),
    ('14/12/2015', '3190.0'),
    ('14/12/2015', '5940.0')
]
```

and converts it to

```
[
    ('09/12/2015', [('09/12/2015', '9380.0'), ('09/12/2015', '7667.0')]),
    ('10/12/2015', [('10/12/2015', '3190.0'),]),
    ('14/12/2015', [('14/12/2015', '3190.0'), ('14/12/2015', '5940.0')])
]
```

(ie a sub-list for each day). You can then easily get the per-day subtotals (which is what the `day_total = sum(...)` line is doing).

**Edit3:** I have added in the start-date and end-date checking.

Comment: uh i don't understand program with lambda code can u explain me a little bit ?

Comment: Lambdas are functions without a name. `lambda x: x[0]` is a function that returns the first item in a sequence. Note that the `return` keyword must be omitted.

Comment: i'm still confused with this groupby function, and day_total line

Comment: This is almost certainly the most efficient solution on the CPython reference interpreter. You could do `from operator import itemgetter` and pass the `groupby` `key` function as `itemgetter(0)` to move even more work to the C layer (avoid `lambda`s or separately defined functions in favor of self-documenting utility functions).

Comment: how i can implement here date range which user entries, this program will print dates and sum from from whole file ?

Comment: Ok i will test this and use, thanks alot for answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to datetime, just use an OrderedDict to group and sum:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
with open("in.csv") as f:
    od = OrderedDict()
    # dte = date string, f = number
    for dte, f in csv.reader(f,delimiter="|"):
        # cast to float
        f = float(f)
        # if we have not seen the key before,
        #  it will get added  with default value of 0
        od.setdefault(dte, 0)
        # access by key/date and add to value
        od[dte] += f

for t in od.items():
    print("{} ---> {}".format(*t))
```

Output:

```
09/12/2015 ---> 17047.0
10/12/2015 ---> 3190.0
14/12/2015 ---> 9130.0
```

If you want to look up a particular date you can access using the datestring.

```
print(od[start])
17047.0
```

Comment: could you comment your code and explain me a little bit, can't figure out 100%

Comment: @Blurred, I added some comments, it is pretty straightforward, we group by date and add each number as we go

Answer (score 0):

Just read the data into a list that ends up looking like this:

```
data = [[date_1, price_1], [date_2, price_2], ..., [date_n, price_n]]
```

Then use this bit of code:

```
from operator import itemgetter

prices = {}
for entry in data:
    try:
        prices[entry[0]] += entry[1]
    except KeyError:
        prices[entry[0]] = entry[1]

sorted_prices = sorted(prices.items(), key=itemgetter(0))
```

I haven't tested this, but this is the right idea. Depending on how much data you're working with, you might want to use a solution that keeps the data sorted as it goes. That would require a lot of data to be necessary though. You could use `OrderedDict` from the `collections` library in such a case.

Comment: i don't need to sort data , dates will be always on ascending order, also can u rewrite this using lists?

Comment: Dictionaries aren't sorted in the name of efficiency. So you lose the ordering of the data. So I sorted it after adding up the values. The `sorted_prices` variable ends up being a list.

Answer (score 0):

I found using dict to accumulate the price easier to understand, however you may disagree:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

#read in data
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as report:
    alldata = [row for row in
               csv.reader(report, delimiter = "|")]

#define a dict to store each date (as key) and price (as value)
datePrice = {}

#use dict.get function to accumulate price
for row in alldata:
    dateKey = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d/%m/%Y")
    datePrice[dateKey] =  datePrice.get(dateKey, 0) + float(row[1])

#make a sorted list of keys and iterate through the list
for date in sorted(datePrice):
    print("{0} -> {1}".format(datetime.strftime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
                              , datePrice[date]))
```

This was the output:

```
>09/12/2015 -> 17047.0
>10/12/2015 -> 3190.0
>14/12/2015 -> 9130.0
```